# Passing unique pointer child as a reference

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

VulkanSurface.h:

```
#include "VulkanInstance.h"

class VulkanSurface {
public:
    //Only constructor
    VulkanSurface(VulkanInstance &instance); //line 14
};
```

VulkanSurface.cpp:

```
VulkanSurface::VulkanSurface(VulkanInstance &instance) {
    //...
}
```

VulkanInstance.cpp:

```
VulkanInstance::VulkanInstance(const std::vector<const char*> validationLayers) :
validationLayers(validationLayers) {
...
}
```

main.cpp:

```
instance = std::make_unique<VulkanInstance>(validationLayers);
surface = std::make_unique<VulkanSurface>(*instance); //line 104
```

This shows no errors in VisualStudio in form of red squiggly line, but the compilation fails with the following:

```
1>main.cpp
1>c:\users\karlovsky120\source\repos\vulkanproject\vulkanproject\vulkansurface.h(14): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'VulkanInstance'
1>c:\users\karlovsky120\source\repos\vulkanproject\vulkanproject\main.cpp(104): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'VulkanSurface'
1>c:\users\karlovsky120\source\repos\vulkanproject\vulkanproject\main.cpp(104): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>c:\users\karlovsky120\source\repos\vulkanproject\vulkanproject\main.cpp(104): error C2672: 'std::make_unique': no matching overloaded function found
1>VulkanInstance.cpp
1>c:\users\karlovsky120\source\repos\vulkanproject\vulkanproject\vulkansurface.h(14): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'VulkanInstance'
```

Comment: Oh wow, I had a few problems there. It's not just a typo though.

Comment: My, mistake.  I though it was a member function, not a constructor.  Vote retracted.  What error are you getting?

Comment: In the code shown, the `unique_ptr` is not holding a valid object (ie, `pTest.get()` returns `nullptr`), so derefencing the `unique_ptr` is **undefined behavior**

Comment: I simplified it too much, give me a minute to get some proper code.

Comment: You need to initialise `pTest` so that it points to something. A pointer that doesn't point to a valid object cannot be dereferenced. You have to allocate a `Test` object for that. You could do this with `std::unique_ptr<Test> pTest = std::make_unique<Test>();` or perhaps `auto pTest = std::make_unique<Test>();`

Comment: You can guard against the problem using `if (pTest.get()) Test2(*pTest);`

Comment: Yeah, the pointer was initialized, I oversimplified the code, these are the chunks of actual code, I can add more per request, but I think the mistake is somewhere in here.

Comment: I guess the copy and move ctors are deleted? What does it say if you change to: `surface = std::make_unique<VulkanSurface>(*instance);`?

Comment: I get ...\vulkansurface.h(14): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'VulkanInstance'

Comment: The code snippet appears to be making an object and then using the copy constructor to make the unique_ptr ... that's probably an oops.

Comment: The mention of an initializer list makes me suspect there are `{ ... }` being used in a spot, even though the code snippet has no curly braces.

Comment: That is a big oops, I fixed it, the error remains.

Comment: I've added the constructor declaration for VulkanInstance, but I use no initializer lists anywhere.

Comment: Could it be that I'm not allowed to pass whatever the unique pointer is guarding so I don't manually delete it and leave unique pointer with a dangling pointer?

Comment: Error persists even if I use regular pointer instead of unique_ptr<VulkanInstance>

Comment: You should probably make a MCVE out of it with enough of the classes to reproduce the problem. It's hard to guess the missing parts. Is the `VulkanInstance` in the `VulkanSurface` a reference?

Comment: It's bizarre.  My project uses Vulkan, but I'm not the developer on the team responsible for working with Vulkan.  I suspect the error message may be misleading as to what the (I'm presuming) underlying real problem is.

Comment: I'll try to whip something up. I want to take VulkanInstance unique_ptr is guarding and pass it as a reference to the constructor of VulkanSurface.

Comment: I'm going to flag this question for deletion and post code in the new one, this has become a real mess.

Comment: Oh FFS, I solved it. VulkanInstance.h was including VulkanSurface.h. Since VulkanInstance.h is evaluated earlier it caused VulkanSurface.h to be included before the declarations of VulkanInstance class, thus the unknown identifier. Respond to this comment that you've read it, I'll delete the whole thing afterwards since it's just a big mess that helps no one.